# Issue with Internal`RealNumberQ in list: How to tell if a given element of a list is real-valued

Tags: number-representation

I define a list of zeros to the equation $y(1-\frac{1}{2}y)^4=0.1$:

```
zeros = NSolve[y (1 - 0.5*y)^4 == 0.1, y];
```

I can call/make the explicit list of solutions.

```
N[{y} /. zeros, MachinePrecision]
{{0.131173}, {0.817044}, {2.09364 - 0.910167 I}, {2.09364 + 
   0.910167 I}, {2.86451}}
```

But I can't check which ones are real, even though the first, second, and last are real:

```
{Internal`RealValuedNumberQ[y]} /. zeros
{{False}, {False}, {False}, {False}, {False}}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Almost all `...Q` functions evaluate immediately.  This is the same as `OddQ[x]` evaluating to `False` right away, before you can substitute something for `x` (because `x` is not an odd number: it is not a number at all, but a symbol).

Comment: `Internal\`RealValuedNumberQ /@ (y /. zeros)` works fine, but doesn't have the same $5 \times 1$ dimensions. You can do `List /@ (...)` if you absolutely need that for whatever reason.

Comment: Also, a warning: if you use internal undocumented functions, make sure you understand what they do.  Try ``Internal`RealValuedNumberQ[0. + 0. I]``.

Comment: From the documentation for `NSolve`: "NSolve[expr, vars, Reals]
finds solutions over the domain of real numbers."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to **check** whether each solution is real:

```
zeros /. {{_ -> _Real} -> True, {_ -> _} -> False}
(* Out: {True, True, False, False, True} *)
```

If you want to **extract** the real-valued solutions only:

```
Cases[zeros, {_ -> _Real}]
(* Out: {{y -> 0.131173}, {y -> 0.817044}, {y -> 2.86451}} *)
```

Comment: Beware that identifying a real number by the head `Real` is shaky. `Real` actually means "floating point, not complex". An exact real number like `Pi` or `Sqrt[2]` doesn't have the `Real` head, and `N[real expression]` can grow parasitic imaginary parts, and thus be `Complex`. `NSolve` results for polynomials are probably OK here.

Comment: @JohnDoty Those are good points. Would you care to edit them into my answer?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the real solutions, you can restrict the domain:

```
NSolve[y (1 - 0.5 y)^4 == 0.1, y, Reals]
```

> {{y -> 0.131173}, {y -> 0.817044}, {y -> 2.86451}}

Comment: This isn't what I had originally intended to ask for, since I already knew about this, but it turns out this was actually all I needed for my solution.